# Trigger Jenkins job based on SCM polling and user

Tags: jenkins, triggers

I'm trying to build a pipeline of jobs that rely on two triggers. I want each job to be triggered based on whether a commit was made to the corresponding Git repository, but I want Jenkins to hold off unless an administrator has enabled the pipeline.

So the steps would be:

1. Administrator triggers a manual build of the entire pipeline, and then
2. Jenkins only builds jobs based on what has changed in Git (and upstream dependencies) since the last build

Step 2 is already working, but I am unsure of how to disable all the jobs in the pipeline and control it so that the pipeline is built only when triggered manually.

Comment: You could use the promotion plugin to that effect: https://github.com/jenkinsci/promoted-builds-plugin.

Comment: admin can option to disable any jobs. If he does that, job and its downstream jobs wont be triggered until he enables the job.so adding step 2 and disbale jobs manually or through scripts ll satisfy your requirement

Answer (score 0):

So, based on what you described, you shouldn't use SCM polling then. Leave only the manual build option. It will still be linked against the SCM and build changes only.